# Use serilog save log records

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to save the printed information to txt text so that we can view important information.

```
Loggers are created using a LoggerConfiguration object:

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().CreateLogger();
Log.Information("No one listens to me!");

// Finally, once just before the application exits...
Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

This is some code I checked the document, I want to save the data in Json format, so that the structure is clear and easy for us to view, what do I need to do, thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring Serilog in ASP.NET Core:

Package:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

appsettings.json:

```
{

  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console "
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Serilogs\\AppLogs.log",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As shown above, the file receiver requires a parameter, in which we need to specify the log file name and file path. This path can be absolute or relative. Here, I specified a relative path, which will create a folder serilogs in the application folder and write to the file AppLogs.log in that folder.

Then add code in startup.cs to read these Serilog settings in the constructor, as shown below：

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
        }
```

Then change the code in program.cs to specify that Host Builder use Serilog in ASP.NET Core instead of the default logger：

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

            .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to add a reference to [Serilog.Sinks.File](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.File/) via nuget.

The next step is to add the destination for Logger:

`.WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(), "log.json")`

The full listing is:

```csharp
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(), "log.json")
    .CreateLogger();
Log.Information("No one listens to me!");
// Finally, once just before the application exits...
Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

The output in `log.json` file is:

```json
{"Timestamp":"2022-01-14T02:49:31.5111479+00:00","Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"No one listens to me!"}
```

Is it what you need?